# Particular solution of $y''−2y'+y=e^t+t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how to guess a particular solution for the following DV?

$y''−2y'+y=e^t+t$

Comment: **Hint:** I assume you meant $e^t$, but try $$y_p = a + b t + c t^2 e^t$$

Comment: @Moo Thanks, but how did you came up with that?

Comment: Is it $e^t$ or $et$?

Comment: @Math Lover $e^t$ sorry

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both $e^t$ and $te^t$ are solutions to the homogeneous equation $$y′′−2y′+y= 0$$

Thus for  your particular solution you need to choose $$ y_p =  At^2e^t+Bt+C$$ and find the constants by plugging $y_p$ in $$ y′′−2y′+y=e^t+t$$